# Python PIP using .cfg

Tags: python, pip

I have a package I am installing in Python that requires dependancies or it fails to install:

```
> pip install http://etc

pak/test.cpp:3:10: fatal error: 
'tools/test.cv' file not found

#include "tools/test.cv"
```

I have been infomred that I need to download the files (which I have done) then...

create a file ~/.tools.cfg containing:

```
[build_ext]
include_dirs=/path/to/home/tools
```

However, I don't understand this last part!

How does the pip installer pick up the .tools.cfg file, where do I even create the file `.tools.cfg`?

I'm running this on a mac if thats makes a difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the path you gave, you make the file in your home directory. On a Mac (OS X, I assume), that is a sub-directory of /Users named for your user name (i.e. `/Users/Sputnik`). You can create it with any text editor, i.e. emacs, vim, nano, TextEdit.app, etc.

I don't know exactly how the pip installer is looking up that file, but presumably it's looking for a file with the name of the package (in this case, tools).

Please comment if this doesn't answer your question, and accept (i.e. click on the Checkmark) if it does!